# My iframe in html is not displaying the contents.Can you please tell me what is wrong in my code?

Tags: html, iframe

Here is my code for html and I have included iframe element to display my "product.html" in my login page. When I click on the link ,product.html,it displays my graph, but when I include in iframe,its not displaying anything[image]
Can you correct my code and tell me my mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
    <meta name='viewport' content="width-device-width initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome</h1>
<div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#Dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">
    Visualization 
    </button>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="/topproduct">Top Products</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
    <a href="#Prediction">Prediction</a>
    <a href="#Register">Register</a>
    <div class="topnav-right">
        <a href="/login">Logout</a>
     </div>
</div>
<div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Chart here</h2>
    <p>.</p>
  </div>
<iframe src="file:///C:/Users/prani/Dev/HelloWorld/Login/templates/product.html" height="1000"     width="1000"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using file:/// just use path to HTML file. Something like this src="templates/product.html"

Comment: Not working,I get this error
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Comment: Is index.html file placed in the same folder as product.html file? If so, do src="product.html"

Comment: all html are in the same folder named templates

Comment: Try this <iframe src="product.html" height="1000"  width="1000"></iframe>

Comment: Can you add your project to https://codesandbox.io/ and send me a link?

Answer (score 0):

You loading the page via `localhost`, but trying to open the iframe from the file system. This is not allowed due to security restrictions n the browser, either load both pages via your local webserver or both direct from the file system